# Finding nth digit of a number in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested-lists

Say you have some nested list 
`[[4,682,31249,81,523],[321741245,7],[349,25,5]]` 
where each element can be of any length and the length of each number can vary also. How can one check each individual number for what the first digit from the left contains? As well as continuing through the number to find the 2nd, 3rd, etc digit.

For simplicity, the program just needs to return one digit at a time, i.e. returns 4, then 6 when called again.

**Expected output:**

```
4,6,3,8,5,3,7,3,2,5 
8,1,1,2,2,4,5 
2,2,3,1,9
```

Comment: Kindly provide an example for output.

Comment: i want the number to get stored in a variable so output can be anything as long as number is isolated from its big number

Comment: That means your 3rd digit would be 8. Right?

Comment: in order of how each number should be returned:
4,6,3,8,5,3,7,3,2,5
then
8,1,1,2,2,4,5
then
2,2,3,1,9

Comment: why 6 in 6,1,1,2,2,4,5 in the 2nd iteration? shouldn't it be 8,1,1,2,2,4,5

Comment: made a typo sorry, supposed to be 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x=[[4,682,31249,81,523],[321741245,7],[349,25,5]]
x=[item for sublist in x for item in sublist]
max_len=len(str(max(x)))
x=[str(y) for y in x]
def digits(x,index):
    digit_list=[]
    for num in x:
        try:
           digit_list.append(num[index])
        except:
           pass
    return digit_list
for index in range(0,max_len):
       print(digits(x,index))
```

Explanation:

1.Intialize x

2.Flat x i.e convert nested list to list

3.Calculate the length of highest number. You can take 'n' on your choice as well. I took it as length of highest number

4.Convert all numbers as string

5.define function digits(). It initializes a list & append single digits according the index called

6.By looping over range(0,max_len/n), call digits() for each index:0-->n

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using python do it as:

```py
nestedArr = [[4,682,31249,81,523],[321741245,7],[349,25,5]]

for arr in nestedArr:
    firstNums = [str(x)[0] for x in arr]
    print(", ".join(firstNums))
```

Comment: this works for isolating the 1st digit, but it fails for the 2nd and 3rd etc...

Comment: Can you provide a sample output?

Comment: see above please

Comment: this still only works for the first digit. Im starting to think what i want is impossible.